# Flexible Wires in CSS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

I want to implement this neat feature into a project I'm working on but port it over to css/javascript/canvas : https://github.com/joshtynjala/flexwires/wiki/getting-started

It basically allows you to drag a wire from place to another -- thus, "wiring" it up.

Where would you start?

Comment: Maybe [Raphael JS](http://raphaeljs.com/)? They have [this demo](http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html)

Comment: @sachleen This looks like it could be great place to start.